# Referencing Previous Variables to Create a New Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, while-loop

I am having an issue with referencing the previous value in the newly created variable to create the new value. Please see below:

```
i = 0
df_pf_monthly = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06]
starting_dollar_value = 1000
monthly_returns_dollar_list = []
initial_value = (1 + df_pf_monthly[i]) * starting_dollar_value
monthly_returns_dollar_list.append(initial_value)

for val in df_pf_monthly:
  second_value = (1 + df_pf_monthly) * initial_value
  monthly_returns_dollar_list.append(second_value)
print(monthly_returns_dollar_list[3])
i += 1
```

Comment: Please describe the _issue_.

Comment: The list I'm actually using is much bigger and I need to loop through the whole list. The list has 188 values and I'd prefer to not write out each line (~188) to achieve every value

Comment: In your question, you said "I am having an issue".  What is the issue?

Comment: It is not clear (at least to me) what you're trying to do or why you would need to write out 188 values to do it. Please describe what you are trying to do and the problem with it.

Comment: Instead of using a loop counter `i`; why not just

``` for val in df_pf_monthly:
         do_something
```

Comment: What I need to do is for every iteration, the value that is referenced needs to be the previous value and I am having difficult doing that. I will then put everything into a list I can reference. Here is some updated code, but I am still having trouble referencing the values:

Answer (score 1):

Don't really understand your issue, but if you are trying to update initial_value you just need to save second_value on initial_value after each loop iteration.

Also, I guess you should be calculating second_value with val, not with df_pf_monthly.

If that was not the problem at all, please tell me more about it!

Answer (score 0):

```
'''
df_pf_monthly = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06]
i = 0
starting_dollar_value = 1000
monthly_returns_dollar_list = [1000]

for val in df_pf_monthly:
  second_value = (1 + val) * monthly_returns_dollar_list[i]
  monthly_returns_dollar_list.append(second_value)
  i += 1
print(monthly_returns_dollar_list)

'''
```